# Pre-request script doesn't change the collection variable using Postman

Tags: javascript, testing, postman, postman-pre-request-script

Pre-Request Script:

```
let user_id = pm.collectionVariables.get("user_id");
pm.sendRequest(`http://security.postman-breakable.com/account/${user_id}/summary`, function (err, response) {
    if(response.status == "FORBIDDEN"){
        pm.collectionVariables.set("status_code", 403);
    }else if(response.status == "OK"){
        pm.collectionVariables.set("status_code",200);
    }
});
```

Test:

```
let status_code = parseInt(pm.collectionVariables.get("status_code"));
pm.test(`Status code is ${status_code}`, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(status_code);
});
```

[The response code is 200 but it reads the previous response code which was 403.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB1fB.png)

Although I try to change my collection variable called "status_code" by writing pre-request script when the response code changes, it doesn't change.

Comment: Probably `pm.sendRequest` remains pending when you read the status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can replicate this 100% of the time. Searching for a solution brought me here.

I truly think it's a bug: it seems that Pre-request Scripts (in 10.8.7) get either a shallow copy of whatever state Collection Variables were in at time of Send, or the binding between `pm.collectionVariables` and Collection Variables has broken. I can't imagine that this behavior is intentional.

For now, I would suggest that you refactor this into a Request and have code in a Test do the `pm.collectionVariables.set()`

The following doesn't apply to your specific use case, but perhaps it will be relevant to whomever finds this question before the bug is fixed: for my own use I built a utility object with a function to manipulate a "cleanup" list in Collection Variables, but changes wouldn't persist. The workaround for my case is to pass the `pm.collectionVariables` reference from the Test sandbox at call-time, since that instance seems bound to Collection Variables in the UI.

My Collection's Pre-request Script:

```
utils = {
    addCleanup: (collection, route, id) => {
        const list = JSON.parse(collection.get('test_cleanup_list'));
        list.push({ route, id, id_field: `${route}id`});
        collection.set('test_cleanup_list', JSON.stringify(list));
        return list;
    }
};
```

and then from a Test in a Request later in the Run:

```
utils.addCleanup(pm.collectionVariables, 'account', account.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce a similar behaviour, any chance you did something like this? Where the pre-request script calls a different endpoint than the actual request?

[image]

Also, don't know if it can help, in my postman the `Forbidden` was not uppercase

Comment: I checked again, endpoints are same and the forbidden is uppercase in my case.

Comment: Can you share the user id? So i can try the exact endpoint you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I send a request in *collection level pre-request script*, save a value from the response in a collection variable (in my case the value is the entire request body stringified) and then try to get the value in the *request's pre-request script*.

Since this is a variable that I use in other places in my collection, I first unset it and then save the new one just in case. In the collection pre-request script I added a log with the collection variable value and it contains the expected request body.

All good so far, but when I manually send the request that reads the same variable in the pre-request script, it holds the data of a previously sent request. I first thought that the pre-request script request takes too long and it proceeds to request execution before the value is saved but when I added a wait, I see in the logs that the variable value is correct.

I have no idea why it takes previous request data. The most shocking part is that the same stale data remains even when I execute the request multiple times (again, I see in the logs when I get the collection variable that the value is changed). When I remove the variable from the collection and execute only this request, all works as expected.

**EDIT:**
After trying a few more things to see what may causes the issue, it looks like that it only reproduces when the collection variable is set within the scope of the `pm.sendRequest` function. When it's set outside of it, the value is stored successfully.

The problem remains but there is a workaround at least.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35020339)